# Can we use sstableloader when the cluster is in partially upgraded state?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, bigdata

We have a cluster with 2 nodes on dse4.8 and one on dse4.5 . can we use sstableloader to stream snapshot data of dse4.5 in the cluster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming is one of the operations you should avoid until your cluster is fully upgraded. Note during an upgrade you may see a schema mismatch across nodes. The upgrade limitations docs here outline some of the things you should avoid:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdDSE47to48.html#upgrdDSE47to48__upglim

I can see that you're upgrading to DSE4.8 from DSE4.5. These versions use Cassandra 2.1 and 2.0 respectively. The sstable format changed between these two versions. So make sure you run `upgradesstables` also

It would be a good idea to complete your upgrade and then try to stream the data. You should use the DSE4.8 / C2.1 sstableloader to do the loading. It should stream in the older format tables. The following jira seems to infer that support for this was added

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5772